# Returning Text files based on date then return certain lines to a listox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have the following basic code that extracts all the data from a text file and deposits it into a listbox (zMailbox is declared at the top of the class)

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

Dim finfo As New IO.DirectoryInfo(zMailbox)

For Each fi In finfo.GetFiles("*.txt")

ListBox1.Items.Add(IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fi.Name)) 'filename only

Next

End Sub
```

The information contained in the text box looks like this...

```
    Unit Name = 
    Unit Code = 
    Operation =  
    Requirements = 
    Last Audit Date =
    Last Auditor = 
    Date Planned =
```

Within the folder that text file is located there could be up to 20 different text files but with differing data. What I'm struggling with is adapting the code to look through all the text files and if the line "Date Planned = " matches the date selected from a date picker then to copy and append the information after the "=" on the lines Unit Code, Unit Name, Operation and apply to the listbox

Any advice would be gratefully received

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution which can be fairly easily extended.

How does it work?

1. Button pressed -> txt file names grabbed from path
2. Each txt file is opened, read line by line
3. Each line is split on the '=' and inserted into a data object so it can be queried
4. We then search that list of dataobjects for our value and return the whole file's contents
5. The file contents are outputted to console

Code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim zMailbox As String = "C:\Windows\Temp\Test"
    Dim allFiles As New List(Of String)
    Dim allFileContents As New List(Of FileLine)

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        'grab list of all txt files
        allFiles = fetchFileNames(zMailbox)
        'read all of the text files and tidy the data
        processFiles(allFiles)
        'search the collected data for 'Date Planned'
        Dim fileContents As List(Of FileLine) = searchCleanData("Date Planned")
        'now we have our file with 'Date Planned' in write all of the lines out to the console.
        If Not fileContents Is Nothing AndAlso fileContents.Count > 0 Then
            'output the filepath so we know which file we are looking at
            Console.WriteLine("File: " & fileContents(0).FilePath)
            For Each line In fileContents
                Console.WriteLine(line.Title & " - " & line.Val)
            Next
        End If
    End Sub
    ''' <summary>
    ''' use linq to find a single file in a list of files that matches a criteria
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="searchText"></param>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Private Function searchCleanData(ByVal searchText As String) As List(Of FileLine)
        Dim returnVar As New List(Of FileLine)
        'find the first filename that contains the value
        Dim fileName = (From line In allFileContents
                    Where line.Title = searchText
                    Select line.FilePath).FirstOrDefault
        'if there is a filename that matches the value return it's contents
        If Not fileName Is Nothing AndAlso Not fileName Is String.Empty Then
            returnVar = (From line In allFileContents
                        Where line.FilePath = fileName
                        Select line).ToList
            Return returnVar
        End If
    End Function
    Private Sub processFiles(ByVal fileNames As List(Of String))
        For Each filePath In fileNames
            Dim contents As List(Of String) = fetchFileContents(filePath)
            'process the individual lines
            allFileContents = splitLines(contents, filePath)
        Next
    End Sub
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Split a list of strings on '=' 
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="fileContents"></param>
    ''' <param name="filepath"></param>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Private Function splitLines(ByVal fileContents As List(Of String), ByVal filepath As String) As List(Of FileLine)
        'return variable
        Dim returnLines As New List(Of FileLine)
        For Each line In fileContents
            Dim currentLine As New FileLine
            'split the current line on the '=' character
            Dim splitline As String() = line.Split("=")
            'now the string should be in two parts, the first being the title, the second being the value
            currentLine.Title = (splitline(0)).Trim
            currentLine.Val = (splitline(1)).Trim
            'attach the filepath so we can search by it
            currentLine.FilePath = filepath
            'add to return var
            returnLines.Add(currentLine)
        Next
        Return returnLines
    End Function
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Search dir for txt files and return all filenames
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="directory"></param>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Private Function fetchFileNames(ByVal directory As String) As List(Of String)
        Dim allFiles As New List(Of String)
        Dim finfo As New IO.DirectoryInfo(zMailbox)
        For Each fi In finfo.GetFiles("*.txt")
            'add the filepath to our list of paths to process
            allFiles.Add(fi.FullName)
            ListBox1.Items.Add(IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fi.Name)) 'filename only
        Next
        Return allFiles
    End Function
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Read a textfile line by line to a list of strings
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="fullFilePath"></param>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Private Function fetchFileContents(ByVal fullFilePath As String) As List(Of String)
        Dim allLines As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
        Try
            Dim reader As New System.IO.StreamReader(fullFilePath)
            Do While Not reader.EndOfStream
                allLines.Add(reader.ReadLine())
            Loop
            reader.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return Nothing
        End Try
        Return allLines
    End Function

End Class
Public Class FileLine
    Public Property FilePath As String
    Public Property Title As String
    Public Property Val As String
End Class
```

Comment: Brilliant, i'll give it a try and let you know! Thanks very much

Comment: Given it a go however I'm not sure if I missing the bit where it selects the files that have the 'Date Planned =' line matching the output of a date picker. I'll have a play. Thanks